# How to get the same date time in two formats in command line?

Tags: terminal, command-line, encoding, time

I have the following code

```
DATETIME=$(date '+%F %T') 
GIT_TAG_DATETIME=$(date '+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S' --date="$DATETIME")
```

to assign the same datetime in two vars in different formats. It works on Linux, but it fails on Macos with

```
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

Problem can be locale-depndent, mine is

```
% echo $DATETIME
2022-04-25 13:58:50
% locale
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: First I don't believe it works in Linux as you want - why have you used a day of month formatter instead of an hour formatter in '+%Y%m%d-%D%M%S' and also spaces around the = . So please edit the code to be EXACTLY what you tried

Comment: It's a typo while posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that GNU/Linux uses the GNU date executable and macOS uses the BSD one. They take different arguments.

See `man date` for the correct arguments.

I think you want

```
DATETIME=$(date '+%F %T')
GIT_TAG_DATETIME=$(date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'  "$DATETIME")
```

giving

```
% echo $DATETIME
2022-04-25 12:50:04

% echo $GIT_TAG_DATETIME
Mon 25 Apr 2022 12:50:04 BST
```

Comment: But this doesn't work on Linux! How to write portable?

Comment: @Dims Check whether you run on macOS or Linux, and then use the appropriate commands.

Comment: I think final answer is `date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' "$DATETIME" '+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S'` and you also made a typo (`%I`)?